# How to delete a user session by admin forcely

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications

I have a problem where I have to delete the user session forcefully if the admin  has changed user's role.

For example:
There are two users (A & B)
They have logged in two different browsers. (IE & Chrome)
Users A is a normal user and user B is a admin user.

User A has logged in to a application and mid of the operation, by the time admin has logged in to the application and have changed the role of the user A

Here I need to be log off user's A session.

I need some ideas on this problem.

Thanks in Advance.
Udhayakumar

Comment: What do you mean by "logged in?"  Are you giving them a cookie for authentication?  Are they logging in using challenge/response or are you authenticating against a database or against DNS?  Are you talking about terminating the user's session?  Your question is unclear, as is.  Please clarify.

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet Hi David, thanks for reply. Logged in means the user's successful authentication to the application. We do authentication against database. Yes I'm talking about terminating user's session.

Comment: See Sanjeev's response, below, then.  I think he's right - you need something to store away a session in a table somewhere & be able to selectively terminate that session.

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet yes. I'm working out his idea. Thought  to let him know once done it . thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is a [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) which stores all the sessions when they are created, you can possibly map them with the userid. When a admin (assuming you can differentiate admin and normal user here) user logs in, he takes the session from the map and call the invalidate() method on that session.

Comment: Hi sanjeev, thanks for the answer. Working out the idea. Update you once done